# Post a private message to multiple users using Yammer Rest API

Tags: private-messaging, yammer

I am able to post one private message at a time. So yammer displays only two participants of that conversation. How can I add multiple users at the time of posting message?

Answer (score 0):

Posting private messages has to be done one at a time since that is how PMs are intended to be used. You might be better off looking [activity stories](https://developer.yammer.com/opengraph/) rather than PMs. You can deliver these to multiple users in one shot, and it is less annoying for users to receive these automated posts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you're looking for
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post

> direct_to_user_ids:   array of integers
>
> Send a private message to one or more users, specified by ID.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's too late now but I ended up on this question a few months back looking for the same thing. It may help someone else in need, you never know :)